# Padding not working in article html5

Tags: html, padding

I have this html file and css [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FxaJr), but when I tried to set the padding of the article tag, there is no effect. Cloud anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursory inspection of the element shows that the `padding` is being overridden. If you examine the rule that is providing the new value of `0rem` you'll note that it comes from line 26 of index.html.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It gets overridden on the bottom of your CSS file:

```
header, article, section, .module {
  padding: 0rem;
}
```

You should remove `article` from there.